# What sizes for @3x, @2x, etc should I provide for an Image inside LaunchScreen.storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, uiimage, uikit

I have the UIImageView pinned to all the borders of the LaunchScreen.storyboard:

[image]

I am using Assets.xcassets for providing the image to the UIImageView:

[image]

I would like that launchscreen's image to be shown properly on iPhone 5, 5S, 6, 6S, 7.

I am not sure what sizes I should make for the Image.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First approach:**

You can use LaunchImage in your assets catalog to add images for every screen resolution you support. Also you can check screen resolution for all devices [here](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions).

[image]

After you add your images select them here:

`Your target` -> `General` -> `App Icons and Launch Images` section -> Launch Images Source

**Second approach:**

If for some reason you don't want to use static images and prefer to have `LaunchScreen.storyboard` with `UIImageView`, you can just add the biggest resolution for each scale (1x, 2x, 3x):

**1x -> iPhone 4: 320x480**

You don't need this image if you don't support iOS 7 and lower.

**2x -> iPhone 6/6s: 750 x 1334**

Yes, you have other devices with different resolution:

- 5/5s (640 x 1136) - image will be downscaled
- 4s (640x960) - use `Aspect Fill` content mode for your image view and it will crop top and bottom

**3x -> iPhone 6 plus: 1242 x 2208**

Comment: i'd appreciate you took the time to answer the question thanks man!